# Uploadify - Positioning queue items inside different containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, uploadify

How can I individually assign each queue element into its own, isolated, parent container? Similar to how facebook photo uploads, each queue item falls into its own thumbnail placeholder container.

Say I have 3 photos being uploaded -- 3 elements in the queue. For each file (image) being uploaded, I construct an edit panel to crop, add a caption, etc.. While each of the 3 files  are in progress, I want the progress bar in the queue to exist in each of these 3 corresponding edit panels. Is this achievable?

---

Visual example:
[image: Demo image]

This question is not targeted towards using a custom queue container to hold all the progress rows, with `queueID: containerID`.

Comment: You are trying to do with options, what you should be doing using [events](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/)

Comment: I'm not trying to do it with options, I know that I need to intercept the event with a callback to be able to assign its positioning, but I'm currently unaware of such an event existing .. is it possible? Otherwise I'll just add a trigger into the JS package

Comment: (just noticed your link and took another glance) Damn, i must have looked over that because i read through all of them.. Alright so I see that this event will give me the queue ID, in which I can now access its element from the DOM (as its element ID is simply prefixed by a constant and postfixed with the queue ID). should be all good, if you want to make an answer I'll mark it, otherwise i'll be answering this shortly.